# How to implement multiple auth providers with react native expo-auth-session and firebase?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-oauth

Hello and thanks in advance for your help.
I am struggling with implementing various auth providers with Firebase & expo-auth-session.

basically, the below code works well for Google login but I'd like to put all the "Google" logic in a separate file and add other files for additional providers. So that I can call the relevant function from the LoginScreen.js. Below the working code, I also pasted what I've tried but it resulted in having a hook error (Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component).

Has anyone an idea on how to manage this promptAsync() with multiple providers and separated files ?

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { AppTitle, Screen, AppLink, SpecialText, AppButtonPrimary, AppText, ActivityIndicator } from "../../components";
import routes from "../../navigation/routes";
import colors from "../../config/colors";
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { signInWithCredential, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from '../../config/firebase';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import logger from '../../utility/logger'

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [loadingPage, setLoadingPage] = useState(false)
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      setLoadingPage(true)
      const { id_token } = response.params;
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
      logUser(auth, credential);
    }
  }, [response]);

  async function logUser(auth, credential) {
    try {
      const result = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
      const user = result.user // User is signed in
      // Some code
    } catch(err) {
      logger.log(err)
      // Some code
    }
  }

  return (
    <Screen style={styles.container}>
      <ActivityIndicator visible={loadingPage}/>
      <AppTitle style={styles.title} size={30}>Connectez-vous à votre compte</AppTitle>
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <AppButtonPrimary
          text="Email"
          icon="envelope-o"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.LOGIN_EMAIL_SCREEN)}
          width={"80%"}
          backColor={colors.white}
          textColor={colors.grayDark}
        />
        <AppButtonPrimary
          text="Google"
          icon="google"
          onPress={() => {promptAsync()}} // <=== how to pass a function here instead of this promptAsync ?!
          width={"80%"}
          backColor={colors.white}
          textColor={colors.grayDark}
        />
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginHorizontal:10,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  buttons: {
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 20,
  }
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

// HERE IS WHAT I'VE TRIED
// LoginScreen.js

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { AppTitle, Screen, AppLink, SpecialText, AppButtonPrimary, AppText, ActivityIndicator } from "../../components";
import routes from "../../navigation/routes";
import colors from "../../config/colors";
import googleAuth from "../../auth/googleAuth";
import facebookAuth from "../../auth/facebookAuth";


function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [loadingPage, setLoadingPage] = useState(false)
  
  function googleSignIn() {
    setLoadingPage(true)
    googleAuth()
  }
  
  return (
    <Screen style={styles.container}>
      <ActivityIndicator visible={loadingPage}/>
      <AppTitle style={styles.title} size={30}>Connectez-vous à votre compte</AppTitle>
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <AppButtonPrimary
          text="Email"
          icon="envelope-o"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.LOGIN_EMAIL_SCREEN)}
          width={"80%"}
          backColor={colors.white}
          textColor={colors.grayDark}
        />
        <AppButtonPrimary
          text="Google"
          icon="google"
          onPress={googleSignIn} // <=== here
          width={"80%"}
          backColor={colors.white}
          textColor={colors.grayDark}
        />
        <AppButtonPrimary
          text="Facebook"
          icon="facebook"
          onPress={facebookSignIn} // <=== this is the idea (having multiple providers with their own logic in a separate file)
          width={"80%"}
          backColor={colors.white}
          textColor={colors.grayDark}
        />
      </View>
    </Screen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginHorizontal:10,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  buttons: {
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 20,
  }
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

// And the googleAuth.js

```js
// Infrastructure
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { ResponseType } from 'expo-auth-session';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

// Firebase
import { signInWithCredential, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from '../../app/config/firebase';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

function googleAuth() {

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest(
        {
          clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        },
    );
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
        const { id_token } = response.params;
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
        logUser(auth, credential);
        }
    }, [response]);
    
    async function logUser(auth, credential) {
        try {
            const result = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
            const user = result.user // User is signed in
            // Some Code
        } catch(err) {
            // Some Code
        }
    }
}

export default googleAuth
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same thing.